# Qpid Proton (Java) - send() method frequently hangs when sending to ActiveMQ queue

Tags: java, activemq-classic, qpid

I'm using Qpid Proton (proton-j-0.13.0) to send messages over AMQP to an ActiveMQ 5.12.0 queue. On a development machine, where ActiveMQ and the Java program run on the same machine, this is working fine. On a test environment, where ActiveMQ is running on a separate server, we see the send() method hangs in 15 to 20 percent of the cases. The CPU also remains around 100% when the send() method hangt. When the send() succeeds, it completes within 0.1 seconds.

Statements to perform a send are similar to this:

```
final Messenger messenger = Messenger.Factory.create();
messenger.start;
messenger.put(message); // one message of 1 KByte
messenger.send(1);
messenger.stop();
```

I'm aware Messenger.send(int n) is a blocking method. However, I don't know why it would block my calls. I can add a timeout and try to resend the message, but that's a workaround instead of a proper solution.

Statements to receive the sent messages from ActiveMQ are similar to this:

```
this.messenger = Messenger.Factory.create();
this.messenger.start();
this.messenger.subscribe(this.address);

while (this.isRunning) {
    try {
        this.messenger.recv(1);
        while (this.messenger.incoming() > 0) {
            final Message message = this.messenger.get();
            this.messageListener.onMessage(message);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception while receiving messages", e);
        }
}
```

Am I missing something simple, being a Qpid newbie? Could this be configuration in ActiveMQ? Is it normal to add a timeout and retry? Any help to resolve this would appreciated.